# How to add text from span tag to data-attr by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tags, attr

How to add text from span tag to data-attr?

Example:
I have this code

```html
<div class="clearfix colelem" id="u92-5"><!-- content -->
     <p>Icon<span id="u92-2">iconsymbol</span></p>
    </div>
```

And I want to add iconsymbol to data-attr="iconsymbol" of the same element like a:

```html
<div class="clearfix colelem" id="u92-5" data-attr="iconsymbol"><!-- content -->
         <p>Icon<span id="u92-2">iconsymbol</span></p>
        </div>
```

Yes and it will be with all elements which has a title="icon"

```js
<script> 
    $( document ).ready(function() {
     $("[title*='icon']").attr('data-attr',function(){ 
   // I don't know
        }).removeAttr('title');
    });
</script>
```

Do you know how to do it?
So I know it is very simple but I am new in jquery and I need in your help.
I hope you understood my question.

Comment: I dont see any element with title as icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that should work for you. There is probably a few ways you can pull this off, but this should hopefully get you started. Please see the attached JSFiddle to see this example in action

```
$(function() {
    $('[title*="icon"] span').each(function(){
        $(this).parent().closest('div').attr('data-attr', $(this).text())
    });
});
```

Here is another way you can do this as well

```
$('[title*="icon"]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-attr', $(this).children().closest('span').text());
});
```

### [JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/v4mubdjp/)

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div>`s should have attribute `title="icon"`

You are using a callback to `attr()` function, so return the value which you need to set inside the function using `.text()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[title='icon']").attr('data-attr', function () {
        return $(this).find('span').text();
    }).removeAttr('title');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fzayg6an/2/)**